# Win8 multiple freezes

Tags: windows-8, freeze

On the Win8 machiene of a friend of mine he recently started experiencing short freezes. This includes his keyboard, mouse, teamspeak, and he appears to have a low framerate on games, even though the games state a reasonable framerate.

He tried rebooting, obviously, replugging his peripherals, and a full virus scan. His cpu usage and ram appear to be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a hdd problem

Comment: look if he has DPC issues: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263